# Namenode not starting -su: /home/hduser/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-14.04, hadoop2, hadoop-2.7.2

Installed Hadoop 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 15.10

Everything is working fine, only when I hit JPS , I can see all the demons running, except namenode .

at start it shows : -`su: /home/hduser/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: No such file or directory`

When I googled it I came to know that , I can ignore this , as my

```
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
```

are set properly and hduser ( the user which runs the hadoop) owns the permission for these folders

any clue ??

Comment: Edit your question with NameNode logs in `logs` directory.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time , this simple change worked for me .

press ifconfig.

copy ip address

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

comment this line

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
```

add the following line

```
10.0.2.15(your ip address) Hadoop-NameNode
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be problem due to frequent Namenode format. Please see the namenode logs in logger.
**Probable solution :**
Check your hadoop.tmp.dir in core-site.xml.
On that location, make sure that you have same clusterid for namenode and datanode(otherwise make them same).
You can see clusterid inside VERSION file in dfs/name/current and dfs/data/current. If that make sense.